# Unable to retrieve individual blog in react using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios

I have spent a couple of time trying to figure out why I'm not able to obtain individual blog post detail page using axios. The code does not return any data (It is returning undefined)
I have the follow code:

```
/public
/src
    /components
        /blog
            BlogPosts.js
            BlogDetail.js
            ... 
    App.js
       import BlogDetail from './components/blog/BlogDetail';
   
The routing for the DETAIL_POST is:
<Route exact path='/blog/:id' component={BlogDetail} />
```

```
DETAIL_POST COMPONENT

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default const BlogDetail = (props) => {
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const slug = props.match.params.id;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(`https://example.com/blog/${slug}`);
                setBlog(res.data);
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [props.match.params.id]);

    const createBlog = () => {
        return {__html: blog.body}
    };

    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (word) => {
        if (word)
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        return '';
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createBlog()} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

BlogPost COMPONENT

```
const Blog = () => {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBlogs = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/blog/post`);
                setBlogs(res.data);
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        }

        fetchBlogs();
    }, []);
const getBlogs = () => {
        let list = [];
        let result = [];
        
        blogs.map(blogPost => {
            return list.push(
                <div className="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                    
                        <p className="card-text mb-auto">{blogPost.introduction}</p>
                        <Link to={`/blog/${blogPost.slug}`} className="stretched-link">Read More</Link>
           
                </div>
            );
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 2) {
            result.push(
                <div key={i} className='row mb-2'>
                    <div className='col-md-6'>
                        {list[i]}
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-6'>
                        {list[i+1] ? list[i+1] : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return result;
    };
return (
    <div className="jumbotron p-4 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
        {getBlogs()}
    </div>
    );
};

export default Blog;
```

On checking the browser console I saw this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` but I can't find where the error is because other components are returning data except the particular one.
The code returns data for those I practice with but never works in my case but everything seems to be similar to theirs.

Comment: 2 things: (1) Is the route path defined to have an `id` match param? (2) Is the request being made? Check the network tab for this. Can you update your question to include your routing code? The router, the code rendering this `blog_detail` (*which should be ***CamelCased***, BTW since it's a React component*), and how you are linking to this route?

Comment: @Drew I have updated the post by making necessary adjustment. I added the routing too. Also, the component isn't returning any data. Pls what else could be responsible for the error?

Comment: Did you also check the network tab to ensure you are making the request correctly? What is the response in the network tab? What is the value of `res.data` in `fetchData` function? Does the `blog` state value have a `body` property?

Comment: I checked the network tab. The request is being made but what is being returned is undefined

Comment: I really do not know why it's returning undefined

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know if I understood your statement very well. The url I am assessing on the browser is : http://localhost:3000/blog/undefined

Comment: I have updated it, pls check

Comment: Somewhere in your app should be either a `Link` component or a `history.push` where you are navigating to a "/blog/XXXXX" url. That is what we need to see.

Comment: Oh, what I have there that links to the detail page is ```<Link to={`/blog/${blogPost.slug}`} >Read More</Link>```

Comment: @Drew pls check, I have added it

Comment: Pls check, I have added it to the last block of code

Comment: And what is the ***value*** of `blogs` you are mapping?

Comment: Api call is been made to the backend, so the value of blogs ought to be obtained from setBlog method

Comment: Ok, so are you landing on blog detail page with a valid `id` param/slug value and making a request to the backend? Can you share the request URL so we can verify/validate the request and response? The requested computed URL from `\`https://example.com/blog/${slug}\``, what is a valid slug value being used to make this request?

Comment: Thanks. I havew learnt a lot from your stepwise troubleshooting. I have have been able to fix the error, it is not from react but from my backend. I did not add slug to the list of filed in serializers.py. After adding it the problem got fixed

Answer (score 0):

Check the network tab to see the type of response which is fetched or if the request is made or not then make necessary changes.

Comment: I checked the network tab. The request is being made but what is being returned is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question happens to be simple, I couldn't have made such a mistake. In case anybody encounters similar issue and the frontend seems to work fine, here is the approach I took. I checked `serializers.py` in the backend app and saw that I did not add `slug` to the field even if I have slug in blog post `models.py`. Adding slug to fields in `serializers.py1 fixed the issue